# Does the Omission of finite number of terms affect the absolute convergence of a series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does the Omission of finite number of terms affect the absolute convergence of a series ?
I know omission or addition of finite number of terms doesn't affect the convergence of a series. Is it true for the absolute convergence also ?

Comment: No, doesn't effect it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{f(n)}$ is also absolutely convergent series.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1748486/show-that-sum-n-0-infty-a-fn-is-also-absolutely-convergent-series)

Comment: Absolute convergence of a series is equivalent to convergence of the series of absolute values, so...